# Help parsing XML with DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, xml-namespaces

I am trying to parse a youtube playlist field.

The URL is: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/664AA68C6E6BA19B?v=2

I need: Title, Video ID, and Default thumbnail.

I can easily get the title but I'm a little lost when it comes to the nested elements

```
        $data = new DOMDocument();
        if($data->load("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/664AA68C6E6BA19B?v=2"))
        {       
            foreach ($data->getElementsByTagName('entry') as $video)
            {
                $title = $video->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
                $id    = ??
                $thumb = ??                 
            }
        }
```

Here is the XML (I have stripped out the elements that are irrelevant for this example)

```
<entry gd:etag="W/&quot;AkYGSXc9cSp7ImA9Wx9VGEk.&quot;">    
    <title>A GoPro Weekend On The Ice</title>

    <media:group>
        <media:thumbnail url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/yk6wkfVNFQE/default.jpg" height="90" width="120" time="00:02:07" yt:name="default" />          
        <yt:videoid>yk6wkfVNFQE</yt:videoid>
    </media:group>

</entry>
```

I need the "videoid" and the "url" from thumbnail-default

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Similar to the [`getElementsByTagName()`](http://php.net/domelement.getelementsbytagname) that you're already using, to access namespaced elements (recognisable by `namespace:element-name`) you can use the [`getElementsByTagNameNS()`](http://php.net/domelement.getelementsbytagnamens) method.

The documenation (linked above) should give you the technical lowdown on how to use it, suffice to say it will be similar to the following (also using [`getAttribute()`](http://php.net/domelement.getattribute)).

```
$yt    = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007';
$media = 'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/';

// Inside your loop
$id    = $video->getElementsByTagNameNS($yt, 'videoid')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$thumb = $video->getElementsByTagNameNS($media, 'thumbnail')->item(0)->getAttribute('url');
```

Hopefully that should give you a spring-board to leap into accessing namespaced items within your XML documents.

Comment: hi, why do u assign $media to search.yahoo.com.mrss??

Comment: @nuttynibbles 1. so the URL could be reused. 2. because SO has a narrow code box.